# Excel modifed date is changing when running package

Tags: ssis

I have a problem when loading data from excel source(excel 2010). When ever I run the package, the excel file modified date is changing to the current date. Even if I change the excel connection properties also, the file modified date is changing. How can I resolve this issue? I am using Dataflow task and excel source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any other solution than setting read-only attribute on Excel and PowerPoint files to avoid that Excel (2010, 2007, 2003) and PowerPoint (2010, 2007, 2003) modify the binary data stream of the file without changing last modification date on just opening the file for reading and closing without making any change and therefore without explicit save.

I could see on comparing the binary files (*.xls, *.pps) before and after viewing the Excel/PowerPoint file with last modification date unchanged, but byte stream changed with (PowerPoint) or without (Excel) a change of file size, that those 2 applications from the Microsoft Office package always record in the file the name of the user who last opened the file, even when the file was not modified at all.

Microsoft Word (2010, 2007, 2003) does not modify the byte stream of *.doc files on just opening the document for reading. I could see this behavior only on Excel and PowerPoint.

I have not tested if other versions of Excel and PowerPoint than from Office 2010, 2007, 2003 make changes on file contents on just opening the file for viewing.

I would be really interested in if there is a registry value which could be set to avoid the modification of Excel and PowerPoint files on just viewing them.

See also [How to prevent Excel from modifying the file on exit?](https://superuser.com/questions/664549/how-to-prevent-excel-from-modifying-the-file-on-exit)